# N-bit x containing L 1s

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, combinatorics

Is there any fast algorithms that can store all the various N-bit numbers that contain L bits of 1s? With N and L parameters provided. It's for breaking a crypto system in class, and I've noticed with two timing attacks I can find out the bit length (N) and the number of 1 bits (L).

Instead of brute-forcing all values between the lower and upper limits, I'd rather minimize the elements I need to test for. Therefore, I was thinking of having a vector that contained all the elements that it could possibly be fitting the information I obtain from the 2 timing attacks.

Any tips at all would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using C++.

Comment: What are the ranges for N and L? There are N!/(N-L)!/L! numbers and that might easily become quite a large number.

Comment: There are N choose L possibilities, and if L = N/2, then there are not so many fewer than 2^N (on the order of 2^N/sqrt(N)). Are there any other side channels?

Comment: No other side channels, the max size of N is 160 bits. I'm hoping that makes it a bit more feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) page shows how to enumerate all binary numbers with exactly n bits set using O(1) work per number generated. Their solution is reprinted here:

> Suppose we have a pattern of N bits set to 1 in an integer and we want
>   the next permutation of N 1 bits in a lexicographical sense. For
>   example, if N is 3 and the bit pattern is 00010011, the next patterns
>   would be 00010101, 00010110, 00011001,00011010, 00011100, 00100011,
>   and so forth. The following is a fast way to compute the next
>   permutation.
>
> ```
> unsigned int v; // current permutation of bits
> unsigned int w; // next permutation of bits
>
> unsigned int t = v | (v - 1); // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
>
> // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change,
> // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
> w = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
> ```
>
> The `__builtin_ctz(v)` GNU C compiler intrinsic for x86 CPUs returns the number of trailing zeros. If you are using Microsoft compilers for
>   x86, the intrinsic is `_BitScanForward`. These both emit a bsf
>   instruction, but equivalents may be available for other architectures.
>   If not, then consider using one of the methods for counting the
>   consecutive zero bits mentioned earlier. Here is another version that
>   tends to be slower because of its division operator, but it does not
>   require counting the trailing zeros.
>
> ```
> unsigned int t = (v | (v - 1)) + 1;
> w = t | ((((t & -t) / (v & -v)) >> 1) - 1);
> ```

Starting with a number of all 0's except for the last L bits, which are all 1's, you should be able to use this to enumerate all the numbers you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty sure that will help.

Answer (score 2):

Damn... templatetypedef got in an answer that's likely better than mine. I wrote a recursive algorithm to generate them. Probably not the way you want to go, but it appears to work (Disclaimer: minimal testing!).

I'll leave it here for posterity even though it may not be the best way to accomplish this. Unlike the other answer, this one will leave you with a vector containing all possible combinations. Obviously this is not an ideal approach if you have many millions/billions of combinations! However, I wanted to have fun writing an algorithm to do it. So mission accomplished.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int N = 4;

void addValues(int to_add, int start_pos, bitset<N> const& working, vector<bitset<N>>& values)
{
  // Take all of our possible spots
  for (int i = start_pos; i < N && i <= N - to_add; ++i) {
    auto working_copy(working);
    working_copy[i] = 1;

    // We have more bits to set...
    if (to_add > 1) {
      addValues(to_add - 1, i + 1, working_copy, values);
    } 
    // We've set all the bits, so this is a working combination
    else {
      values.push_back(working_copy);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  int L = 2;

  vector<bitset<N>> values;
  bitset<N> working;
  addValues(L, 0, working, values);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```